# Inserting line before lines containing a particular word

Tags: windows, regex, find-and-replace, textpad

How to insert a line before a line ending with a certain word in textpad?  For eg: I want to insert a blank line before every line that ends with the word 'Chapter'

Comment: okay but why you want to do and from where you want to do. write complete question.

Comment: You should install [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com) and then try smc's answer below.

Comment: I think OP wants a solution for textpad

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a use of [regex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)-based search/replace functionality.
Search for

> `(.*Chapter)(\r\n)`

Replace with

> `(\r\n)(\1)(\r\n)`

This will do exactly what you have asked: add a new line before every line that ends with the word Chapter. Note, this does not consider fullstop at the end of the sentence since you did not mention it.

Comment: good answer, thanks @Art Gertner. I use your regex to update mine.  I succed to add a new line with some words, before the line that starts with Word. The regex becomes: SEARCH: `(.*Word.*)\r` REPLACE BY: `OTHER TEXT\r\r\1\r`